# For a population proportion experiment, do we have to perform both a z-test and z-confidence interval?

Tags: random, statistics

A reminder in advance, I only knows the basic for statistics!

I'm doing a project concerning whether or not random number generators follow the Benford's Law. My population is the random numbers generated by random.org.

So my question is, in an experiment do I have to perform both a z-test and z-confidence interval? Please ask me to clarify if needed since I'm still not knowledgeable about this topic...thanks!

Comment: This is a place for programming problems, not stat. There's another site that deals with that: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ideally, you should because you are taking a randomly generated sample. But your null hypothesis when performing the z-test for say your first digit = 1 must be H0 probability (or proportion) at 1 = 0.18.